# NetLogo: How to calculate infinite series (or partial sum) with NetLogo?

Tags: sum, netlogo, series, infinite

How to calculate infinite series with NetLogo?
For example, how to calculate the sum of x^i, where i is from 0 to 10?
(the lower bound of summation is i=0 and the upper bound of summation is i=10 (or infinite), x is an indexed variable representing each successive term in the series)

Comment: Just to clarify, x is a 10-element vector of numbers?  I.e., sum(x(i)^i) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do infinite series, NetLogo doesn't have algebraic manipulation. However, you can construct a function that takes the relevant powers and adds them together.

I think this is what you want:

```
to-report sum-power [#x #upper]
  let range-list range (#upper + 1)
  let result reduce [ [so-far next] -> #x ^ next + so-far ] range-list
  report result
end
```

For example, `sum-power 2 3` returns 14 because the first is (0 + 2^1), then add 2^2, then 2^3 = 0 + 2 + 4 + 8